CMake not recognizing header files in raylib
I am trying to compile raylib for WASM. I'll preface this by saying I am inexperienced in CMake. I've cloned the repository and in the root directory I run:
cmake -DPLATFORM=Web .

This runs with no errors.
Next I build the project:
cmake --build .

It spits out this error:

fatal error: 'GLES3/gl3.h' file not found
862 |     #include <GLES3/gl3.h>              // OpenGL ES 3.0 library

Now I recognize that CMake cannot find the header, but as far as I am aware this line in the CMakeLists.txt ensures that CMake can find the header in the project:
add_subdirectory(src raylib)

How can I fix this? Why won't it compile?
Thanks.

For build the project with emscripten you need either run emcmake instead of cmake or pass additional -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE option for point to the emscripten toolchain: https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/wiki/Working-for-Web-(HTML5)#23-using-cmake
